# Layout chemfig/schemestart

Tags: chemfig, chemistry

for a report I'm currently writing I wanted to include some chemical reactions. Most of them are fairly easy to put into LaTeX but I'm having some trouble with the more complex reactions. A picture is shown in which my output is shown but I'm quite unhappy with the looks of it since it is poorly aligned.
[image]

My code is shown below:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,oneside]{report}
\usepackage{chemfig,chemmacros}
\setchemfig{+ sep left=1em, + sep right=1em, arrow offset=1em}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}\small
\begin{equation}
\scalebox{0.7}{
 \schemestart
  \chemfig{O=[:330]-[:30]-[:330]-[:30](=[:90]O)-[:330]}
  \+{2em, 2em, 3em}
  \text{2}\chemfig{[0.4]*5(-=(-[:45])-O-=)}
  \arrow{->[H$^+$]}
  \chemfig{[0.4]*5(-=(-[:30](-[:330]([-0.4]*5(=-=(-)-O-)))-[:90]-[:45]-[:90](=[:135]O)-[:45])-O-(-)=)}
  \+{2em, 2em, 3em}
  \chemfig{H-[:30]O-[:330]H}
 \schemestop
 }
 \label{eq:RB2}
\end{equation}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

I was wondering whether someone could help me out!

Comment: Please make your code snippet be compilable, then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Comment: How do you want this reaction to align? _Chemfig_  takes the first atom of a structure as baseline alignment. Look at the thin line underneath the examples in its manual.

Comment: Why are you using the **equation**  environment? Is that because you want to add numbers and labels to your reaction schemes? If so, I would recommend the **reactions** module of the _chemmacros_ package. That module is designed to just do that.

Comment: And another comment .. sorry. You are loading both _chemmacros_ and _mhchem_. Delete the line loading _mhchem_ and the word _chemmacros_ next to _chemfig_. To use the modules of _chemmacros_ add the following lines: `\usepackage[modules={reactions]{chemmacros}` and `\chemsetup{formula=chemformula}` or `\chemsetup{formula=mhchem}`. The latter will load the _mhchem_  package, but the manual says it may be error prone. The _chemformula_ package is far superior to _mhchem_ in handling and tweaking formulas, so I would recommend using that package. Changing `\ce` to `\ch` should do mostly it.

Comment: @alchemist I don't believe that using mhchem with chemmacros actually leads to any problems. None that I know of at least. (For me chemformula has the advantage that I can react to any problems in either of the packages, hence my recommendation.)

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to create a separate figure, insert it into the text and then reduce its size if necessary.

I changed the starting point of the pentagonal ring, because chemfig aligns the molecules by the starting point.

```
\documentclass[11pt,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{chemfig,chemmacros}
\setchemfig{+ sep left=1em, + sep right=1em, arrow offset=1em}

\begin{document}

                \schemestart
                \chemfig{O=[:330]-[:30]-[:330]-[:30](=[:90]O)-[:330]}
                \+
                \text{2}$\left(\chemfig{[0.4]*5([:-54]=-=(-)-O-)}\right)$
                \arrow(--.mid west){->[H$^+$]}
                \chemfig{[0.4]*5([:-54](-)=-=(-[:30](-[:330]([-0.4]*5(=-=@{z}(-)-O-)))-[:90]-[:45]-[:90](=[:135]O)-[:45])-O-(-))}
                \arrow(@{z}--){0}[,.7]\+
                \arrow{0}[,.3]
                \chemfig{H-[:30]O-[:330]H}
                \schemestop
\end{document}
```

[image]